# Are these 2 soap headers the same?

Tags: php, soap, soapheader

I've been told that my soap header must be like this :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com">
<soap:Header>
    <axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">
        urn:uuid:FA7EB13C84D91BC34B1373986557015
    </axis2:ServiceGroupId>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
    ...
</soap:Body>
```

My soap header is :

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns1=\"http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com\">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:ServiceGroupId>
        urn:uuid:FA7EB13C84D91BC34B1373986557015
    </ns1:ServiceGroupId>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    ...
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Mine doesn't work. I searched for a solution but I couldn't find anything. How can I fix this? Or which topics should I learn?

Comment: Have you tried the one your producer suggested?

Comment: No, I couldnt generate producer's header. I use php and when i use setSoapHeaders($header); it creates mine soapheader

Comment: Muhammed, how you can fix the issue? Please look my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737554/difference-between-two-soap-requests. I couldnt fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` is [SOAP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/) and requested is `http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/`, the [SOAP 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part0/) namespace.

Don't get confused by the `soap`/`SOAP-ENV` or `axis`/`ns1`, they are just namespace prefixes.

Also your first message seems to be missing the declaration of the `axis2` namespace prefix, but I suppose `xmlns:ws="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com"` is meant to read `xmlns:axis2="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com"`.

If the provider asks you to send SOAP 1.2, then use a SOAP 1.2 namespace and message format. This is why relevant code should be present in your question, but you need to [instantiate your `SoapClient` like this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php):

```
$client = new SoapClient("some.wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2));
```

Comment: Doesn't make any problem to create <ns1> tag instead of <axis2> tag?

Comment: No, that are just [namespace prefixes](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#NT-PrefixedName).