# Difference between two soap requests

Tags: php, soap, apache-axis, soap-client, soapheader

**My SOAP Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com" xmlns:ns2="ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">
    <env:Header>
        <ns2:ServiceGroupId>
            <BOGUS>urn:uuid:7C2F61BDE7CB9D9C6D1424938568724</BOGUS>
        </ns2:ServiceGroupId>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:getGunlukParametreRapor>
            <date>2015-02-22T00:00Z</date>
        </ns1:getGunlukParametreRapor>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**Expected SOAP Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com">
   <soap:Header>
       <axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">urn:uuid:479731898147E116AD1424691518968</axis2:ServiceGroupId>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ws:getGunlukParametreRapor>
         <date>2015-02-22T00:00Z</date>
      </ws:getGunlukParametreRapor>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

#### Tried with following codes:

```
$options = array(
        'trace'       => 1,
        'exceptions'  => 1,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2
    );
$client = new SoapClient("http://dgpysws.pmum.gov.tr/dgpys/services/EVDServis.wsdl", $options);

$p1 = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage->UserName = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage->UserName->v = "Username";
$p1->loginMessage->Password = new stdCLass();
$p1->loginMessage->Password->v = "Passwor";
$client->login($p1);

$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http//ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2', 'ServiceGroupId', "UNIQUEID", false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);    
$result = $client->getGunlukParametreRapor(array('date' => '2015-02-22T00:00Z'));
```

#### Question is:

1. These SOAP requests are same?

I'm using `SOAP_1_2` and it should be like `Expected SOAP Request` but my request doesnt looks like to expected format. Missing where?

2. How can i get the output like as expected?

*Note: dgpysws.pmum.gov.tr wsdl address is private area.*

Comment: I used pmum webservice 2 years before. I couldn't get response from php or java. I used these webservice by using c#.

Comment: exa.= 
stringBuilder2.Append("<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:ws=\"http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com\">");

            stringBuilder2.Append("<soap:Header>");

            stringBuilder2.Append("<axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2=\"http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2\">urn:uuid:");

            stringBuilder2.Append(sessionId);

            stringBuilder2.Append("</axis2:ServiceGroupId>");

            stringBuilder2.Append("</soap:Header>");

            stringBuilder2.Append("<soap:Body>");

            stringBuilder2.Append("<ws:getGunOncesiFiyat>");

Comment: @MuhammedTanrıverdi OMG! It is bad, so bad news for me! This `exa` what for, C#? I can login `PMUM` but when i try to get data, i got `Authorization error!` error allways. I think this issue about `xml tags`. I couldnt get output like expected with `axis2` and `ws` tag. Thanks Muhammed for helps.

Comment: Yes its for C# code. You should write each soap code by yourself. And you can contact to person who work in PMUM. I think they would help you. Because my system could not get response from PMUM with old webservice in 2015. I do not know, maybe my account expired or their webservice could be changed. It is better to ask them. Kolay gelsin :)

Comment: @MuhammedTanrıverdi I contact with a person who worked in pmum but not much help. I'm trying to convert xml tags to `axis2` format. I searched, searched, searched on everwhere but not found any solution. Eywallah ;)

Comment: I can not write the email here who was the responsible person :) But I found a webpage, you can contact with this email.  https://gunce.pmum.gov.tr/?p=239

Comment: @Bora why don't you post your php code?

Comment: @Alex Updated question with php codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same. To get rid of the BOGUS node you need to use this:

```
$strHeaderComponent_Session = "<SessionHeader><ServiceGroupId>$theVarWithTheIDGoesHere</ServiceGroupId></SessionHeader>";
$objVar_Session_Inside = new SoapVar($strHeaderComponent_Session, XSD_ANYXML,
                                     null, null, null);
$objHeader_Session_Outside = new SoapHeader('http//ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2', 
                                           'SessionHeader', $objVar_Session_Inside);

// More than one header can be provided in this array.
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($objHeader_Session_Outside));
```

Comment: So `ws:` tag in body and `soap:` tags?

Comment: Those are just prefixes for the namespaces, which in turn you define using something like this: `xmlns:ws="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com"` As long as you use the corresponding URI namespace, you should be fine.

Comment: Added the code to actually set the headers not only to define them.

Answer (score 1):

**try the following**

```
$ns = 'http//ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2'; //Namespace of the WS.
//Body of the Soap Header.
$headerbody = array('ServiceGroupId' => $UNIQUEID_Token);
//Create Soap Header.       
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'axis2', $headerbody);             
//set the Headers of Soap Client.
$soap_client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Output `<ns2:axis2><item><key>ServiceGroupId</key><value<BOGUS>urn:uuid:640CF5726E4167C14F1425399974506</BOGUS></value></item></ns2:axis2>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com" xmlns:ns2="ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">
    <env:Header>
        <ns2:ServiceGroupId>
            urn:uuid:7C2F61BDE7CB9D9C6D1424938568724
        </ns2:ServiceGroupId>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:getGunlukParametreRapor>
            <date>2015-02-22T00:00Z</date>
        </ns1:getGunlukParametreRapor>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ws="http://ws.dgpys.deloitte.com">
   <soap:Header>
       <axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">urn:uuid:479731898147E116AD1424691518968</axis2:ServiceGroupId>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ws:getGunlukParametreRapor>
         <date>2015-02-22T00:00Z</date>
      </ws:getGunlukParametreRapor>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Are the same. 
env=soap, ns2=ws and ns2=axis2. You can have any prefix to refer to these namespaces as you like. Once you assign the prefix you just refer to it using that in the other places. Only diff was the bogus tag tin first request. Just remove that.